# Фон в Unity 2D (Android)

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-android, unity3d-editor, unity3d-ui

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно изменить фон в Юнити 2д? Когда хочу поменять фон, накладывается на другие спрайты
[image: Фиолетовый квадрат - п]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В юнити существует иерархия отрисовки наследников, она влияет на порядок отрисовки вашего изображения. Расположите фон первым в списке дочерних объектов вашего Canvas. Вы также можете растянуть ваш фон по размеру всего вашего Canvas. Настройка находится в поле Stretch компонента Rect Transform в окне инспектора.

Comment: Огромное спасибо!